# Javascript Angular using code from different .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an Angular4 project and I have created a filter on my **app.component.ts** which I'm currently using on my **app.component.html**.

```
<button (click)="filterBy('cars')">Cars</button>
```

This works fine in this file by I want to use this same filter on my **nav.component.html** but I'd like to avoid recreating the filter code again on the **nav.component.ts**.

Is there a way of using this filter on my **nav.component.html** from **app.component.ts** ?

Comment: This looks like a good use case for a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create service, for example "filter.service.ts". Good thing in service is - it will create only one instance. So you use less memory, and app is faster. 
Then - you can include it to the parent module:

```
import { FilterService } from "some/filter.service.ts";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, NavComponent],
  providers: [ FilterService ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

And use in your components like this:

```
import { FilterService } from "some/filter.service.ts";

constructor(filter: FilterService) {
  this.filter = filter;
}
```

And then your html:

```
<button (click)="filter.filterBy('cars')">Cars</button>
```

Comment: Would I need to create a new file for the service and take the relevant code out of app.component.ts?

Comment: sure, method 'filterBy' should be moved to the service.

Comment: in case you need to extract some value of the method, you create another method in component, that calls "this.filter.filterBy", that will return the value you need.

Answer (score 2):

Migrate your created filter code in some new .ts file. Import this file in your app.component and other components by using import {ClassName} from file.ts syntax and then easily implement it in your component html code

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable()
export class Service{
  //create all the logic here for all the things you want to be shared across compponents
}

call this in the component you want to use like 

import {Service} from "../shared/service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-angular4'
})
export class Angular4Component implements OnInit {
     constructor(private service:Service) {

 // resuse all the methods
}
```

Comment: this is different from the below answer as we are using angular DI which should be used when using services which is to used in multiple components